# Pandas ranking within multiple groupby levels

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

[image]I am trying to sort within multiple levels of a groupby multi-index dataframe based on an aggregated value. For an idea of what I'm talking about:

I have a hierarchal data set that is then grouped on multiple levels. I then aggregate and sum a certain measure on them. I then want to rank them within each other.

At level 0, values should be ranked in descending based on sum of said measure. Then within level 1, values should be ranked in descending order again  based on sum of said measure, level 2 and so on..

After a groupby, how do I sort at every level?

I know not providing an example is tough, but if I could be pointed in the right direction that'd be great, thanks

EDIT:
Original Data:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=[['a','car',6], ['a','bike',7], ['a','car',8], ['b','bike',9], ['b','car',10], ['b','bike',11]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Groupby:

```
df.groupby(['a','b']).agg({'c':'sum'})
```

Desired Output after resetting index:

```
 pd.DataFrame(data=[['b','bike',20], ['b','car',10], ['a','car',14], ['a','bike',7]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: Please post a DataFrame and desired output, in other words, a [mcve]

Comment: I've added an example where I want to sort at each column a b c

Comment: Please post the dataframes as text, and include a desired output

Comment: Ive added the text for the dataframes not sure how to copy them in

Comment: Can you explain to me how you arrive at `['b','car',14]`? It does not make sense that you would `groupby(['a','b'])` and then `agg({'c': 'sum'})` only to then dissociate these values via your sorting method. The value of 14 is produced via the some of 8 and 6, which are values associated with `a` and `car`, not `b`.

Comment: b comes first, because when we sum up the ‘c’ column, b has the greater sum. Then within b, ‘car’ is greater than bike so it comes first. I need to get the sum of ‘c’ on all three levels and this was my attempt at it, not sure if this is the best way

Comment: I understand what you are **trying** to do, but it does not make sense the way you are outputting your desired dataframe, because the value of 14 is not associated in any way with 'b' and 'car'.

Comment: I had the values switched, I've updated it with the correct information, the first value is now 20 which corresponds with 9+11 for b and bike

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

I will break this up into multiple steps (note that I changed your column names for clarity purposes, i.e. `df.columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3']`):

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0    a   car     6
1    a  bike     7
2    a   car     8
3    b  bike     9
4    b   car    10
5    b  bike    11
```

**Step 1**

We first want to `groupby('Col1')` and use `transform(sum)` to transform the dataframe based on the sum of the values in `Col3` associated with a given group. This sets your order for `Col1` by using `sort_values('Col3', ascending=False)` to store the resulting index and use that to set the index of the original dataframe `df`.

```
step1 = df.iloc[df.groupby('Col1').transform(sum).sort_values('Col3', ascending=False).index]
```

Which gives:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
3    b  bike     9
4    b   car    10
5    b  bike    11
0    a   car     6
1    a  bike     7
2    a   car     8
```

**Step 2**

Now we can simply group by `Col1` and `Col2`, using `sort=False` to preserve the sort order from Step 1, and aggregate based on the sum of `Col3`. Use `reset_index()` to clean up the index and restore your original columns.

```
step2 = step1.groupby(['Col1','Col2'], sort=False).agg({'Col3': 'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Your desired output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0    b  bike    20
1    b   car    10
2    a   car    14
3    a  bike     7
```

Comment: Not his desired output.

Comment: I would like 'b' to be before 'a' because the sum is greater

Comment: Which sum are you referring to here? Can you explain using the output in my answer and I will modify accordingly?

Comment: In my edit, I included my desired output. In this case, the sum of 'c'. Grouped by my 'a' column, the sum of 'b's value are greater than that of 'a's so the value 'b' should come first

Comment: I've updated my answer, thank you for the clarification of your requirements.